# Laravel - Selecting the database to use at login

Tags: mysql, authentication, laravel, multi-tenant

I'm just starting to learn Laravel and I managed to use the Auth class for a simple login.

Now, what is required for my application is the following:

I have a global database called 'global' which has some tables, including 'sysadmins' and 'tenants'. I also have a database for each tenant, called 'tenant_{id}' where {id} is the id of the tenant.
Also, in each 'tenant_{id}' database there is a 'users' table.

So, when the users logs in, he should give his email (or username), password AND the id of the tenant he belongs to (some might suggest that I identify through subdomains, well that's not the issue for now).
So, the user would input [john], [* * * *], [5].

Now he should be authenticated against the 'tenant_5'.'users' table and it should be defined globally that the database for his session is the 'tenant_5' database.
So, when he a model like Car::all();, the database that is used is, you guessed it, 'tenant_5'.

I've spent the entire day searching for a solution and experimenting but I don't understand enough of the framework to tweak it too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved this myself:

First of all, we create a route group to the subdomain, excluding 'www' with a pattern:

```
Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');

Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.mysite.com', 'before' => 'switchDB'), function() {
    // Publicly accessible routes under the subdomain
    Route::group(array('before' => 'guest'), function() {
        // login routes (get and post)
    });

    // Routes under the subdomain that require authentication
    Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    });
});

// Publicly accessible routes in the main domain
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'PublicController@showHome'));
```

Then the filter, where we get the subdomain and check in our default database (global database) what account has that domain. We also check if that database exists.

```
Route::filter('switchDB', function($route, $request) {
    $parts = explode('.', $request->getHost());
    $subdomain = $parts[0];

    $account = Account::where('subdomain', '=', $subdomain)->first();
    if($account == null) {
        App::abort(404);
    }

    $res = DB::select("SHOW DATABASES LIKE '" . $account->db_name . "'");
    if(count($res) == 0) {
        App::abort(404);
    }

    Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $account->db_name);
    DB::reconnect();
    Session::put('subdomain', $subdomain);
});
```

The DB::reconnect() seems to be a key player in all of this.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would set the config at runtime:

```
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', 'tenant_5');
```

Then you could put the database name in the session with:

```
Session::put('db_used', 'tenant_5');
```

And then in your start/global.php file you could do a check:

```
if(Session::has('db_used'))
{
    Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', Session::get('db_used'));
}
```

Not tested but you should be able to do it this way.

Comment: I've seen the Config::set('...'); in other posts, but isn't it applied to all users?

Comment: Ok, I've finally tested it and it seems to work just like I want, although I don't really understand what the 3rd block of code does.

Comment: Sorry didnt see your comments until now. The first block is how you would set the database at runtime, but should be used like in the third block. In the third block we check if the db_used is set in the users session and if it is we set the database config. Do you understand? (:

Comment: I've noticed this fails on the first attempt and then works on the second. Because it puts the 'db_used' in the session and only the Config::set in the global.php works.

Comment: Well in your login method you must have some way to determine wether he's a tenant or something else. Then you would obviously have to set the config there too since the session has not yet been set when you check for it in start/global.php. Just thought that was obvious :)

Comment: It's too dirty this way. I've managed to solve the problem myself in a more laravelish way. I will post an answer soon.

Comment: It's not dirty at all. The start/global.php is yours to play with :)